# React Native NativeWind (Tailwindcss) does not work properly

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mobile, tailwind-css

I'm facing an issue with React Native tailwind classes (NativeWind), as it only works in App.js component.

I have set tailwind config direction for files within to use tw classes, but yet no results:

```
/taillwind.config.js
content: ["./App.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}", "./<custom directory>/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}", "./pages/HomeScreen.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
```

the directory I'm pretty sure is correct, and in some directories it works in some doesn't, anyone's facing this issue aswell, what would be a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Here you need the paths to all of your component files in your tailwind.config.js file. Remember to **replace**  *

> 

1. 

```js
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./App.{js, ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./screens/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

2. With the actual name of your directory e.g. screens.
   Go to the [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started/)  Install the required packages in your React Native project:
3. npm install @react-navigation/native
4. npx expo install react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context

#### Wrap the Rest of your app code. Here is an example.

```js
import * as React from "react";
import {
  NavigationContainer
} from "@react-navigation/native";

export default function App() {
  return ( <
    NavigationContainer > { /* Wrap Rest of your app code */ } <
    /NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Hope It works properly.